# Why every brew has a bitter malty aftertaste?

Tags: temperature, fermentation-temperature, malt, taste, aftertaste

Every of 5 previous brews (lager, pilsner, pale ale, IPA) have had a somewhat bitter and malty aftertaste to them. It's not too off-putting (except the lager) but is clearly there, yet not present on your tongue until swallowed (mostly aftertaste). *What would cause a beer to have this quality*?

5G brews. All liquid malt extracts. Different hop variations. VERY clean during brewing. Water is grocery store spring+distilled. Sugar/powdered(?) for carbonation before bottling. Dark bottles in closet 70-78d. Most have been nicely carbonated, slightly under ABV. Most the time a US-05 yeast is used. The temperature of fermentation have been slightly higher in the 70-78d range. Have done both 1 and 2nd fermentation rounds. Most fermentation times are 2-4 weeks plus 10-14 days in bottles. Nothing out of the ordinary for small-time brewers.

Comment: Bitter and malty can exist together, but they tend to counteract each other - think of a well balanced IPA. We'll need a lot more detail to know what's going on: recipes, OG & FG, exactly which ingredients were shared among the five beers.

Comment: [This question](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/15089/what-makes-a-beer-malty-and-sweet) talks about maltiness in great detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "malty" taste can come from burning the sugars in the beer. When you slowly pour in the LME, vigorously stir the boil to avoid pooling on the bottom of the kettle.

Comment: This is also more likely to happen if you are not boiling the full water.

Comment: On our next brew (yes, 7 months later :( ) we took this suggestion and it worked. While our beer is currently in bottles, we were able to tell based solely on the taste of the fermented beer that the bitter aftertaste is not present in this batch. The beer we brewed was a Dogfish Head 60 clone, plenty of hops, extract, and same yeast as all prior, only thing we changed was the boil, which, while we still used a burner, we kept on very low and stirred the entire hour. With this technique we NO longer have the aforementioned taste apparent in all other brews and it tasted great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of hops and how much?  You may need to increase the IBUs.

Also, what is the extract made from?  Check to make sure it is a 2-Row and not something with more malt backbone (i.e. Pilsner)

You also may want to find a higher attenuation yeast strain.